# Is there a way in a Blazor Server app to get mouse coordinates clicked

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to get motivated to move one of my open source projects called Transparency Maker from Windows Forms to Blazor, so I can put the app online.

All of the image editing is done via text in a language called BQL (Bitmap Query Language) which is very similar to SQL.

The one thing I don't know how to do in Blazor is get the x, y position of where the image is clicked. Windows Forms makes this very simple, although I have to do some scaling.

Is there a JavaScript way of doing this and bringing it into Blazor?

This is a feature I have to have, or writing a query like this is impossible for the user to know what to type:

```
Update
Set Adjust Red -200
Where
X Between 1700 2591 
Y Between 1930 2110 
Total > 500
```

[image: Work At Home Wardrobe Before]

[image: Work At Home Wardrobe After]

Notice the White part of the socks in the second image, only the white was changed because the Total (Red + Blue + Green) has to be greater than 500 to perform the adjustment.

Thanks if this is possible to get the position clicked?

I think more people might appreciate this tool once it is online. As it is, "selling" free software is actually harder than it should be.

Transparency Maker
https://github.com/DataJuggler/TransparencyMaker

Comment: Look for `EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> OnClickCallback`. It has ClientX and Y coordinates.

Comment: The only relevant information here would have been your OnMouseClick event, But you didn't post it.

Comment: BQL? Would love to hear more, currently using OpenCV

Comment: DougS, I have almost finished a new website called PixelDatabase.Net (not live yet, but look for it in a few days). My problem is keep thinking 'This will be a neat feature'... I added some cool stuff today that blow me away, so hopefully someone else likes one of my ideas (for once).

Answer (score 4):

I am posting an answer thanks to the help from dani (if you posted your answer here, I could mark it as the answer).

I had to do two things to make this work:

1. Add a using statement for

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
   ```
2. I added the EventCallback e parameter, and I didn't have to change anything else.

   ```
   public void Button_Clicked(MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       double x = e.ClientX;
   }
   ```

I will probably have to write some trial and error code to go from where the image is located, to find what pixel was actually clicked, but now I am confident I can do this.

Many thanks Dani. I will name a hospital after you some day.